# accessing getter properties from objective-c header in swift

Tags: objective-c, swift, getter

In the objective-c header we have a property like so:

```
@property (nonatomic,assign,getter=isMyThingEnabled) BOOL enableMyThing;
```

In swift any attempt to access this property like so generates an error that the property is not found:

```
myClassInstance.isMyThingEnabled
```

So how do I access the property isMyThingEnabled in swift?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even if you defined a custom name for the getter method in
Objective-C, the access from Swift is still done using 
the property name, so this works:

```
let enabled = myClassInstance.enableMyThing
```

Comment: and the Apple docs say: "Accessor property attributes (getter= and setter=) are ignored by Swift."

Answer (score 0):

You can define a getter to customize the behavior and the returned value of this property but you should use the property name, not the getter name, and the getter shall be invoked automatically